# Using .htaccess to allow access only from one domain

Tags: .htaccess, dns

My case is this, I have a splash screen in my main domain (1) with a button with a link to my subdomain to accept and enter my site thats located in wordpress in the subdomain(2).

- (1) www.maindomain.com
- (2) www.maindomain.com/wordpress/

But if the visitors type the path to my subdomain (www.maindomain.com/wordpress/) they bypass my splash screen and I dont want this to happens so...

I am actually trying to use this code in .htaccess file located in wordpress folder (2) but it did not work, actually it denies access from everywhere.

```
AuthUserFile /dev/null
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName OnlyFromUNO

<Limit GET>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from .maindomain.com
</Limit>
```

Actually I get the Forbidden access to my main and my subdomain (typed directly)

I will be glad to get any help, I checked others alternatives in this site and other but neither worked

Comment: What is the actual requirement? Why must users only come through that splash page?  What about access to the rest of the Wordpress site?